# AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'count' in dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary, count, integer

my question is that i am trying to get dictionary done in google colab but it is getting error of AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'count' in dictionary again and again.

`temp_dict = {"33": [temperatures.count(33)],"34": [temperatures.count(34)],"39": [temperatures.count(39)], "40": [temperatures.count(40)], "42": [temperatures.count(42)],"29": [temperatures.count(29)]}`

this is my code line but it is not able to count in google colab.is there something missing.

Comment: You added the question *you* were asked.  What question are you asking *us*?

Comment: I also didn't understand what is the question, though the code is working in python3

<code>
>>> temperatures = [33, 34, 39, 40, 42, 29, 33, 34, 33, 42, 42]
>>>
>>> temp_dict = {"33": [temperatures.count(33)], "34": [temperatures.count(34)], "39": [temperatures.count(39)], "40": [temperatures.count(40)], "42": [temperatures.count(42)], "29": [temperatures.count(29)]}
>>>
>>> temp_dict
{'33': [3], '34': [2], '39': [1], '40': [1], '42': [3], '29': [1]}
</code>

Answer (score 0):

From what I'm getting is that variable temperatures is not a **list** but the **int**

```
temperatures = [1,2,3,3,4]
print(temperatures.count(1)) # Returns 1
print(temperatures.count(3)) # Returns 2
print(temperatures.count(5)) # Returns 0

# Possible your code
temperatures = 33
print(temperatures.count(33)) # Returns error: AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'count'
```

If you have python 3.11, it will highlight in which part your code error was made, for example

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\******\Desktop\nf\a.py", line 2, in <module>
    print(temperatures.count(33))
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'count'
```